# nonautonomous planar systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution of the following nonautonomous planar system:

$$ X' = AX + (-\cos(t), \sin(t))^T \text{ where }A \text{ is below:}
$$

$$A =\pmatrix{2  & -5   \\
              1 & 2 \\    
              } $$
This resonates damping, and I know that we can start with the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: Were you given any initial conditions?

Comment: No, just it says, Nonautonomous planar system

Comment: See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx).

Comment: could you put in the details here?

Answer (score 2):

You will solve the homogeneous system and arrive at (I changed your variable names, otherwise it gets too ugly):

$\tag 1  \displaystyle x_{h}(t) = x_{1h} + x_{2h} = \sqrt{5}~ c_2 ~ e^{2 t} \sin \sqrt{5} t+c_1 e^{2 t} \cos \sqrt{5} t$

$\tag 2 \displaystyle y_{h}(t) =  y_{1h} + y_{2h} = \frac{c_1 ~ e^{2 t} ~ \sin \sqrt{5} t}{\sqrt{5}}+c_2 ~ e^{2 t} \cos \sqrt{5} t$

Next, you will form the variation of parameters for each of $(1)$ and $(2)$, separately, as:

$w' x_{1h} + f' x_{2h} = 0$, and

$w' x'_{1h} + f' x'_{2h} = -\cos t$

Solve this system for $w'$ and $f'$.

Next, integrate to find $w$ and $f$.

This will give you the particular solution, $x_p(t) = w x_{1h}(t) + f x_{2h}(t)$.

So, your solution for $x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t)$.

Repeat this process for $y(t)$ and make note that the $-\cos t$ is $\sin t$.

You will end up with:

$x(t) = \displaystyle \sqrt{5} c_2 e^{2 t} \sin (\sqrt{5} t)+c_1 e^{2 t} \cos(\sqrt{5} t)- \frac{\sin t}{2}$

$y(t) = \displaystyle \frac{c_1 e^{2 t} \sin(\sqrt{5} t)}{\sqrt{5}}+c_2 e^{2 t} \cos(\sqrt{5} t)+\frac{1}{10} (-2 \sin t - \cos t)$

Make sure that this $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ satisfy your original system!

What a fun problem with many places to make algebra mistakes!

Comment: Can you give some more details on the variation of parameters? also, can you make your answer a bit more complete?

Comment: The answers provided for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the exact answers since no initial conditions are given. You can test those to verify that they satisfy your system. Also, did you try following what I wrote with the link that Mhenni Benghorbal provided? This is not trivial, you really have to sit and crank it out to see why and how it works (Variation of Parmaters). There is also a way to do it as a system with the exponential, but I think that if you are having trouble with this, that wouldn't be of help. Regards

Comment: Very nicely done, and so helpful, too! +1

Comment: That was a difficult problem because they chose ugly solutions to deal with - made the algebra terrible!